# Why column return null value when select from VIEW in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view in SQL Server 2014:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[V242_MachineWTSVirtual] 
AS
     SELECT 
         [242_MachineWTS].*, 
         [242_MO].PartID
     FROM 
         [242_MachineWTS]
     LEFT JOIN 
         [242_MO] ON [242_MachineWTS].MONo = [242_MO].MONo
```

When I execute this `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
    [242_ MachineWTS].*, 
    [242_MO].PartID
FROM 
    [242_MachineWTS]
LEFT JOIN 
    [242_MO] ON [242_MachineWTS].MONo = [242_MO].MONo
```

It returns exactly the desired result, but when I run this `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM V242_MachineWTSVirtual
```

it returns value of `PartID` column is null. I don't know why.

My table `[242_MachineWTS]` has more than 3 million records.

Comment: Did you scroll through all the records. May be order was different am sure both will return similar records

Comment: `SELECT [242_MachineWTS].*, [242_MO].PartID
  FROM [242_MachineWTS]
  LEFT JOIN [242_MO] ON [242_MachineWTS].MONo = [242_MO].MONo Where [242_MO].PartID is null` execute this query and check whether any rows returned or not

Comment: Yes, It returned 806 records is null at PartID but I think it's not problem because when I execute  command, I limited data with condition  Where [242_MachineWTS].date > '2016-06-03' and it return nothing records PartID is null

Comment: Then use the same `where` condition in `View` you wont get `NULL` values in result

Comment: Thank for your help. I fixed temp by the way I reposition [242_MO].PartID to before [242_MachineWTS].*  and alter my view. After that, I execute my view and it returned exactly result but I think it is not solution because I did that before and after short time, I got same problem.

Comment: Please provide table definition or sample data.

Comment: @PhongDao another thing is - don't ever use `select *` in views. This can lead to several "magic" (hard to debug) problems. You should recreate your view with explicitly defined list of columns.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thank for your advice, I will note this thing.